# Are there actions in Sketch 3 like Photoshop?

Tags: sketch-app, actions

I have seen another post, but it is closed and no one answered.

I want to automatize flows like, for example, duplicate a layer and hide the one I have duplicate from. Right now, I have to use chained shortcuts like cmd+h + cmd+d + cmd+h

Answer (score 4):

No, sketch doesn't currently have actions.

Comment: Oh, man! what a bad news. Is it expected to be released?

Comment: @Raimundo it is coming soon http://developer.sketchapp.com/reference/action/